# Pick next message after previous fully processed

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm stucked with that kind of a problem. I use kafka as transport between services. Tried to draw sequence diagram [image]

First of all planning service get main task and handling it, planning service pass it to few services then. My main problem is: **I musn't pick another main task, until f.e. second service send result to kafka and planning service will process the result**.

My main listener have this structure

```
@KafkaListener(
        containerFactory = "genFactory",
        topics = "${main}")
public void listenStartGeneratorTopic( GeneratorMessage message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment){
   
    //do some logic
    //THEN send message to first service, and then in that listener new task sends to second
    sendTaskToQueue(task);
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    log.info("All done in method");
}
```

As I understood, I need aknowledge() after all my logic with result from second service will be done. So I tried to add boolean flag in CompletableFuture, setting it in true when my planning service get response from second service. And do blocking get() in main listener to continue after.

```
private CompletableFuture<Boolean> isMessageProcessed = new CompletableFuture<>();

@KafkaListener(topics = "${report}")
public void listenReport(ReportMessage reportMessage) {
    isMessageProcessed = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
    
    }
}
@KafkaListener(
        containerFactory = "genFactory",
        topics = "${main}")
public void listenStartGeneratorTopic( GeneratorMessage message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment){
   
    //do some logic
    //THEN send message to first service, and then in that listener new task sends to second
    sendTaskToQueue(task);
    isMessageProcessed.join();
    log.info("message is ready for commit");
    acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}
```

That's looks strange enough and that idea doesn't bring me result.
So, can you give me advice, what can I do in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `6  topics?` I believe this is better separation of duties and might allow you better scale,

Guess I would check KStream as well in your case...

My idea goes like this:

PLANNING SERVICE read from `topic1.start` do work send to `topic2` ,

FIRST SERVICE read from `topic2` do work and send to `topic3`

PLANNING SERVICE (another instance) read from `topic3` do work and write to `topic4`

SECOND SERVICE reads `topic4` do work send to `topic5`

PLANNING SERVICE (another instance) read from `topic5` and write to `topic6.done`

Comment: Well, I will try kafka stream. But the idea with 6 topics didn't solve my problem. I musn't pick message from the first topic faster than I push result to topic 6.  And I'm stucked exactly with that problem do u have any ideas?

Comment: You could try using pause() on first topic once it consumed and resume() after the message enters the last topic